# second-order difference equation with variable coefficients $ax_{n+1}-(n+1+a)x_n+nx_{n-1}=-n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

The equation is:
$ax_{n+1}-(n+1+a)x_n+nx_{n-1}=-n$, where $a$ is a constant and $0<a<1$. Any ideas on how to solve it? May be the z-transform is useful? Thank you!

Using the difference operator notation, $[aE^2-(n+2+a)E+(n+1)]x_n=-(n+1)$. I tried to factorize the difference operator but failed.

Comment: You are trying to solve $Lx=-z^1$ where $z^1_n=n$ and $(Lx)_n=ax_{n+1}-(n+1+a)x_n+nx_{n-1}$. A common approach is to compute $Lz^k$, where $z^k_n=n^k$, at least for $k=0$ and $k=1$, and see what happens.

Comment: the solution looks very compligated

Comment: I happened to know that when $x_0=a/2$ and $x_1=(a+1)/2$, $x_n=(n+a)/2$ is a solution. But I have no idea if the initial condition is not like that. How did you solve it? Thanks! @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Comment: $(Lz^k)_n=a(n+1)^k-(n+1+a)n^k+n(n-1)^k$. $(Lz^0)_n=-1$, $(Lz^1)_n=a-2n$, $(Lz^2)_n=-3n^2+(2a+1)n+a$. What should I do next? Thank you so much! @Did

Comment: Using a formal power-series / generating series might be useful here: multiply your equation by $t^n$ and sum over $n=1,2,3,\ldots$. Then take $f(t) = \sum x_n t^n$ and rewrite the equation you have in terms of $t$, $f(t)$ and $f'(t)$. This gives you a ODE for $f(t)$ that hopefully can be solved. If this is possible then once you have the solution you can series expand it and simply read off $x_n$. Note that with the hints above you only need to apply this to the homogenous case (right hand side is $0$).

Comment: @Did the homogeneous problem has confluent hypergeometric functions. Found one dimension out of two.

Comment: @Winther I cannot use the hint in the non homogeneous case?

Comment: @Claire you already have one solution with right hand side $-n.$ You are, therefore, finished with considering non-zero right hand side. Any other solution differs from that by a solution of the homogeneous equation. Apparently that is, by far, the more difficult aspect.

Comment: I should add that the ability to specify the initial conditions, $x_0$ and $x_1,$ in any possible way, is precisely finding the full basis for the solutions of the homogeneous problem. If you have typed in the problem correctly, of course. Where did you get it?

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks! It's very helpful. It's from a model I am working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one solution to the homogeneous equation is given by the confluent hypergeometric function of the second kind, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConfluentHypergeometricFunctionoftheSecondKind.html

I am actually reading Abramowitz and Stegun, pages 504-507 especially.

Identity 13.4.16 reads
$$ (b-a-1)U(a,b-1,z) + (1-b-z)U(a,b,z) + z U(a,b+1,z) = 0. $$
As a result, if we take
$$ y_n = U(1,n+2,z) $$ then
$$ n y_{n -1} - (1+n+z)y_n + z y_{n+1} = 0. $$
If you take this, setting $z$ to your original variable $a,$ you get something in the kernel.

The kernel is dimension two, so there is a linearly independent sequence as well. Anyway, given your specific solution in comment with a polynomial solution to the inhomogeneous problem, any other solutions are fairly horrible.